# In Clojure, what is a good way to compare user input Strings with Longs?

Tags: string, types, clojure

In Clojure I am building a card game. Cards have a suit and a score.

```
{:suit 1 :score 9}
```

The cards are created using ranges, e.g. (range suitTotal), so the class of the values of :suit and :score is Long.
Players send command strings, e.g. "discard1.9" is a discard request.
Using a regex to parse this:

```
(re-seq #"[0-9]+" command)
```

results in String items "1" and "9". A card created with these results would be

```
{:suit "1" :score "9"}
```

I would like this to compare as equal with the original card. At the moment I am using (Integer/parseInt) to convert the strings.

The suit value could be built from a different type, such as a keyword, but the score value is used as a number elsewhere.

Comment: So you've read numbers as strings, and parsed them. What is the question?

Comment: The program is clojure apart from this area. Using Integer/parseInt seems like using java interop and type considerations when there should be a more idiomatic clojure way to achieve this.

Comment: @JamesPetry: +1 but... Curiosity killed the cat: why are you using a notation such as *"discard1.9"*? It doesn't seem very convenient to read: typically in poker software (trackers, hand evaluators, etc) you find notation like *"Ac"*, not "1.9" (where "Ac" stands for "Ace of clubs"). Even if it's just internal your debugging/tracing/commenting sounds like it could be facilitated if you were to keep a notation close to the "real" one no!? Also typically a player has 'x' cards and he doesn't say *"I discard Ac"* he says *"I discard the 2nd card from my hand"* (I mean, from a software standpoint)

Comment: @JamesPetry: especially seen from the other player's side: all they see is *"Player x discarded his 2nd and 5th card"* and they do not know which these cards are. If you do it with *"discard 1.9"* you'll have to then compute the location of "1.9" to know which card was discarded... Which seems weird since that you had that information in the first place, when the player clicked on the card(s) before discarding them. Also, when 'hand histories' are written to disk, other players are not supposed to know which card were discarded by others. I'd go for *"Shows Ac"* and *"Discards 3rd card"* etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A good approach would be to parse the strings as numbers and then use = to compare.

```
user=> (Integer/parseInt "1")
1
```

The advantage of this over read-string is this is more restricted. This won't parse strings that look like clojure data-structures.

Answer (score 4):

use read-string

**DEMO**

```
user=> (read-string "1")
1
```

Comment: can be dangerous with user-provided input..... unless you turn off \*real-eval\* then this can be used to execute arbitrary code.